# JSON: Get the value of radio not with key on form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms, typescript

I want to get the value only on form submit in angular. This is the Code

In my Typescript:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

this.memleticsForm = formBuilder.group({
    changeType: [{}, Validators.required]
});
}


memleticsSubmitForm(form) {
    console.log(form);

  }
```

Html:

```
 <form name="learningtestForm" [formGroup]="memleticsForm" (submit)="memleticsSubmitForm(memleticsForm.value)" novalidate>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>You have a personal or private interest or hobby that you like to do alone.</td>
   <td>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" [value]=0>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" [value]=1>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" [value]=2>
   </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button ion-button block color="secondary" end type="submit">Submit</button>
```

When I clicked a button and submits it, the output on my console.log is "Object {changeType: 2}"

But I want to get only the "2" and use it to compute a value like

```
memleticsSubmitForm(form) {
    var x = form * 5;
console.log(x); // if 2 is clicked it should display 10
}
```

Comment: There's no JSON involved here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could do something like:

```
memleticsSubmitForm(form) {
    console.log(form.changeType);
    const changeType = form.changeType; // Your form has this attribute
    var x = changeType * 5; // So use it ;)
    console.log(x);
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Alejandro Reyes It works but I can't display the number in console.log for the product. It displays NaN

Comment: Probably due to a type issue. You could try parsing the changeType to integers, something like: var x = +changeType * 5;
The + sign is parsing your variable. Cheers!

Comment: still returns a NaN. Why do I get this NaN?

Comment: Could you please do 'console.log(changeType)' and give us the result of it?

Comment: Also you could try, depending on your needs, using form.value.changeType instead of form.changeType. Hope it helps.

Comment: 0, Undefined, NaN

Comment: console.log(form.changeType);
    const changeType = form.ChangeType;
    console.log(changeType)
    var x = +changeType * 5; 
    console.log(x);